# Execute Completion Handler in DispatchGroup

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show server(s) latency in a `UITableView` the only problem is ping result handler wont run under `DispatchQueue`

```
let dispatch_queue = DispatchQueue(label: "PingQueue", qos: .background)
            dispatch_queue.async {
                let client = SimplePingClient()
                client.pingHostname(hostname: self.Servers[indexPath.row].Address, andResultCallback: { result in
                    guard let r = result as? String else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.lblLatency.text = "Timeout"

                        }
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        cell.lblLatency.text = r + " ms"
                    }
                })
            }
```

the `andResultCallback` wont called at all (i dont know why !?)

Comment: where are you calling this?

Comment: @RobertDresler in override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from doing asynchronous stuff without any cache in `cellForRow`. Be aware that cells can be deallocated suddenly. Do your asynchronous tasks in the model.

Comment: To add to what vadian said, it's not just that they can be deallocated, but cells can be reused, so in an async task like this, a cell containing address `X` at the time `self.Servers[indexPath.row]` runs, might be reused and contain address `Y` by the time its `Address` field is dereferenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's a few things you should note about your existing code.

1. Your call to `dispatch_queue.async` is doing the `client` initialization and the invocation of `client.pingHostname` run on the `dispatch_queue.async` queue. Note that because `pingHostname` is an asynchronous API, this returns almost immediately, and doesn't mean that the competition handler will run on `dispatch_queue`.

   - Note that using `dispatch_queue.async` probably doesn't make sense. Assuming client initialization is a lightweight, non-IO dependant task (i.e. it doesn't do any network calls of its own), and assuming pingHostname is lightweight (which it almost certainly is, given that it's an async function of its own), then there's no reason why you can't use a `dispatch_queue.sync` call, or even directly make these calls off your current thread. It'll probably be pretty much just as fast, or perhaps even faster (because async calls make escape analysis much harder, and limit compiler optimization). It has the added benefit of removing the worry of "what if this finished before this next thing? Or what if it's the other way around?".
2. You provide a closure to the asynchronous `pingHostname` API, which it has the freedom to run on any thread/queue it wishes, let's call it queue/thread `X`. The API document will probably shed some light on this.
3. From the context of queue/thread `X`, you make async calls into `DispatchQueue.main`. This is correct; Cocoa is designed to such that all UI updates must always happen from the main thread.

If your stated intention is to run competition handler code on `dispatch_queue`, then you have to either:

1. Provide `dispatch_queue` as a parameter to the `pingHostname` API, so that it can run the competition handler on your queue, instead of whatever default it resorts to otherwise. Of course, this is something the API must have been designed to have.
2. Make your own call to `dispatch_queue.sync` from thread/queue `X` from within the competition handler.

In the absence of a `DispatchQueue` parameter, here is how I would write this:

```
pingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "PingQueue", qos: .background)

let client = SimplePingClient()
client.pingHostname(
    hostname: self.Servers[indexPath.row].Address, // This is jank, but I'm ignoring it for now
    andResultCallback: { _latency in
        pingQueue.sync {
            print("Do some stuff on pingQueue")

            DispatchQueue.main.sync { // enter main queue for UI updates
                cell.lblLatency.text = (_latency as? String).map { $0 + " ms" } ?? "Timeout"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks for your help , but may i ask a question? this block works perfectly , but if i put the client.pingHostname in a async dispatch , why it's handler never called ?

Comment: @KooroshGhorbani Probably something to do with the improper access of `indexPath.row` after the lifetime of the tableview delegate method (which is where I presume this code is being called from)

Answer (score 1):

It's not right to call this inside `cellForRowAt`. You should have somewhere in your ViewController array of results

```
var results = [String]()
```

Now, get results somewhere else, not in `cellForRowAt`. Create custom method for this, or use custom model.

Also better would be if your `pingHostname` method returned all results and then you just assign your `results` array and then reload data of your TableView

```
client.pingHostname { results in
    if let r = result as? [String] {
        self.results = r
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } 
}
```

also use this `results` array as source for TableView's data source methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.lblLatency.text = results[indexPath.row]
    ...
}
```

Comment: An extra array besides the data source array is a very bad idea. That's pretty error-prone. Cells could be (re)moved and you have to keep the number of items in sync and in order.

Comment: @vadian what? This array is source for TableView's data source methods.

Comment: According to the question the data source is `self.Servers`

Comment: thanks,
 a combination of both answers solved my problem :D the main problem is there are so many differences between java and swift aspects :)) and i'm new to swift

Answer (score 0):

The result callback isn’t being called because your ping client is being deallocated before it’s finished.

Make `client` an instance variable instead of a local variable. Set it to `nil` when you’re done with it.

Comment: still won't call the result handler :/